# Move viber to another device without activation?

Tags: viber-messenger

I want to transfer viber from old phone to new, but i don't want viber to send a notification to all my contacts that i joined viber. I hate this option. How can i avoid it? There has to be a way...I've tried Titanium Backup and obviously the activation windows popped out anyway, but how exactly does it detects that it' a new device?

Answer (score 4):

So i did it! Here is how:

1. Both phones need to be rooted.
2. Install Titanium Backup on both phones (I used the pro version). Also install [Device ID](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.redphx.deviceid) on old phone
3. On old phone back up Viber with Titanium
4. On new phone install Xposed framework and the module Xprivacy
5. Move the backup file from old phone to new and restor it (dont launch Viber)
6. Open Device ID on old phone and Xprivacy on the new one.
7. In Xprivacy open settings, and there you can enter the fake info you want to send to apps. We need to copy from old phone Hardware serial, Android ID And advertising ID (advertising ID can be found in Android Settings→Google→Ads). After that tap on viber icon, find *Identification* and check the first box.
8. If all done right the viber app will launch in same condition as on old phone. After that you need to uninstall Xprivacy for better stability of viber.

Comment: @YvetteColomb There's one negative review out of hundreds. That's much more likely to be a confused user than a malicious app. And regardless of whether the app turns out to be malware or not, there's nothing to indicate that this is anything other than a genuine recommendation by another user. That's not spam.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I fully agree with what Dan wrote. Especially consider the "a genuine recommendation by another user" part: onupirat wrote to have used that solution successfully, and might not have noticed that comment. Thanks for your insight – maybe you could name an alternative to obtain those IDs in a safe way? I could e.g. think of some ADB commands, but that might not be the easiest way for a non-techsavvy user :)

Comment: @Izzy you can use apps for them (iv'e written them myself to find the ids of phones I'm using), but not sure how to advise consumers to do so safely. I would never advise people to root their phones and it's something most developers cringe at on SO. so that's where I'm coming from. Whenever you delve into the types of software you need to do that, you compromise your phone and cannot remove it, whether it be the app being recommended here, or the app used to root the phone. You don't need to root a phone to get the deviceId using an android app.

Comment: @YvetteColomb no, not for that. But you need root to install TiBu and also the XPosed framework with Xprivacy in order to fake those data to the Viber app (plus apart from that, the device was already rooted anyway, see the question text). I'm not 100% sure, but isn't that "Device ID" the app-in-question shall give the same one you see when running `adb devices`? So shouldn't one find it even in *Settings › About phone › Status* as "Serial", so that entire "Devide ID" app wouldn't even be needed at all?

Comment: @Izzy It's unclear to me, what ID they are actually using, that's why I'm hesitant. There's quite a few ids and people misname them. So can't answer. Possibly. And yeh it's the whole rooting thing, and it's possible that rooting the phone is what caused the problem with the second app. It's just you can't get the app you use to root your phone off your phone and you don't know how your security is compromised after that. Sorry to cause trouble here, I meant to act in good faith. I'm going to bed now, but am happy to continue a chat tomorrow \o :)

Comment: @YvetteColomb Thanks a lot. May I suggest you then join us in our [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25/android-enthusiasts), so we don't misuse the comments for our discussion? Until then: Good night!